# Umbraco 7 stripped down document editor

Tags: editor, umbraco7

I was wondering if it is possible to provide a dedicated document editor to users (ie without the left hand sections such as 'Content', 'Settings', 'Media' etc) in certain circumstances just to make the editing process smoother.

For example, whilst viewing intranet site, they can click on an article and simply edit on screen without having all the umbraco furniture visible, just the document properties part, they then save and return to viewing the site (They would still need the full Umbraco layout for other activity).

Is this possible? A brute force option I suppose would be to iFrame Umbraco and use css to hide the left hand menu, but hoped there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Maybe https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/frontend-editing/ ?

Comment: Looks exactly the sort of thing I'm after!

Comment: Cool! As it says, though, it's a beta :-)

Comment: The documentation says 'Add a property of the data type "Frontend editable" (which is installed with the package) to the content types that should be editable...' - confused by terminolgy. Not sure about 'Add a property' - do you mean add a new custom property editor (included in the package) to the document type you want to be able to edit with this?

Comment: Not my package, dude, I just googled for it :-/

Comment: Oops - sorry, must read more slowly!